# Counting distinct results and how to use sub queries in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, mariadb

Having some trouble figuring out the best way to do this.

My query is as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM `DataTable` 
WHERE `Type` = 'New' AND 
`Permit` = 'Valid' AND 
YEAR(`IssueDate`)='2012' ORDER BY `Owner` ASC
```

This produces the individual result set I am looking for, but from that subset of data, I need to find out the list of individual (distinct) "Owners", and how many times they occur (count).

I am not sure how to use my query as a sub query and run another query on the results.

I would normally just export the results, then work on it from there, but I have some time today and thought I'd look for some help learning the proper way to do this.

Comment: [Here's a good starting point.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/subqueries.html)

Comment: When you need a list of distinct owners and how many times they occur, that's an aggregate query, meaning one that uses GROUP BY. More info [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html), but basically your query is `SELECT Owner, COUNT(*) FROM DataTable WHERE Type='New' AND Permit='Valid' AND YEAR(IssueDate)=2012 GROUP BY Owner ORDER BY Owner`.

Comment: Thanks for the link AirThomas, and thanks for the explanation Ed!